# PostgreSQL Query given a set of date ranges

Tags: postgresql

```
Table name: sample
   --Item--|---datefrom---|--dateto-- 
   Item A  |0001-01-01    |2099-01-01
   Item B  |2017-11-20    |2017-12-31
   Item C  |2017-11-27    |2017-12-12
```

Supposing we have the data above. How do I construct the query in such a way that I will get what is the current effective item given the date today.

Example. Since today is 2017-11-29 then I should get ITEM C.

I've tried this but I'm just wondering if there is a more effective query for this?

```
select * from sample where datefrom>= (select datefrom from sample where datefrom < '2017-11-29' order by datefrom desc limit 1 ) and dateto <= (select dateto from sample where dateto > '2017-11-29' order by dateto limit 1)
```

Comment: why not just `select * from sample where datefrom <= now() and dateto >=now() order by datefrom limit 1`?

Comment: effective item. Item C should take precedence.

Comment: your query doesnt return any row btw.

Comment: Unrelated, but: in Postgres you can use `-infinity` and `infinity` instead of those "magic dates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return the most recent item whose range overlaps the current date:

```
select *
from
(
    select *,
        row_number() over (order by abs(current_date - datefrom)) rn
    from sample
    where current_date between datefrom and dateto
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If two or more items happened to be tied for the latest, and you want all ties, then just replace `row_number` with `rank`.

But from what I see your Item A has a range which might also include today.  I am not sure why its range starts from the year zero, or if that is even valid/makes sense.

As pointed out by @a_horse we could use the following simplified query if we are certain/don't care about ties between items for being the closest:

```
select *
from sample
where current_date between datefrom and dateto
order by abs(current_date - datefrom)
limit 1;
```

Comment: it acts as a default value in case there is not row returned.

Comment: What determines which item gets reported should there be two or more matches, which sounds like it is always the case?

Comment: It should return the row closest to the current date. E.G. between ITEM A and  ITEM C. ITEM C should take precedence since its the closest.

Comment: Which date defines "closest?"  The to date or the from date?

Comment: You don't need the window function. You can simply use `order by abs(current_date - datefrom) limit 1` in your original version of the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But then we can't handle ties well.  This is a better generic answer.

Comment: it acts as a default value in case there is no row returned by the query. eg. if current_date is 2018-01-01. so by default. ITEM A should be returned.

Comment: @Bigboss You did not answer my question.  Is `datefrom` or `dateto` used to determine proximity to the current date?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen datefrom is used